# Angular momentum of different bodies

Tags: angular-momentum, rotation

How is the change of radius of a dancer spinning around their axis different from the change in the radius of orbit of a satellite revolving around a body? Why doesn't angular momentum remain the same in the latter?

Comment: What is causing the change of radius?

Comment: If the radius is changed by giving the satellite a boost in the tangential direction, then you have a non zero torque on the satellite.

Comment: @Peter as an example, assuming the orbit is reducing because of loss of energy

Comment: Then what is causing the loss of energy?

Comment: let's say atmospheric drag?

Comment: In that case the angular momentum of the satellite is transferred to the air. The total remains constant. Another interesting one is momentum transfer between earth and moon due to tides.

Comment: @Peter Brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: You liked some answers but let me tell you you can even accept the answers by clicking the tick on the left

Answer (score 1):

When the dancer tugs her arms in, the force she exerts points towards her body. If you consider the angular momentum with her body as the origin, that force provides no torque and her angular momentum does not change.

The force that slows down the satellite is probably not a central force. It has a component that is perpendicular to the its radius. That means that it does exert a torque on the satellite, causing the angular momentum of the system to change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
In your answer to the second part, what if the force that slows down the satellite is not tangential, but say, due to loss of mass

Comment: Let's say the satellite explodes into 2 pieces, and the angular momentum of one piece is reduced because of a fall in orbital velocity. Then, the orbital velocity of the other piece must increase from the explosion such that angular momentum is conserved. One way to see this is to realise that the 2 pieces exert equal and opposite forces on each other during the explosion, so the torque acting on both of them sums to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The angular momentum of a satellite in orbit remains the same (actually of planet and satellite) if we can ignore external forces. A satellite in an elliptical orbit will be slower when further away from the planet because the angular momentum is constant.

For a near Earth satellite we need to consider both earth and the satellite. It loses energy to friction with the atmosphere, and as a result its angular momentum is transferred to the atmosphere, but the total (satellite + Earth) remains constant.

The Moon is slowly moving further from the Earth and the Earth's rotation is becoming slower very gradually as a result of angular momentum transfer and energy transfer caused by the tides.